# How to create and display PDF in Internal Storage/Cache using FileProvider?

Tags: android, file, pdf-generation, android-fileprovider, android-internal-storage

Following is the code that create PDF in External Storage.

```
public class CreatePDF {


private static String FILE = "/xyz";
private static Font catFont = new Font(Font.FontFamily.TIMES_ROMAN, 18,
        Font.BOLD);
private static Font redFont = new Font(Font.FontFamily.TIMES_ROMAN, 12,
        Font.NORMAL, BaseColor.RED);
private static Font subFont = new Font(Font.FontFamily.TIMES_ROMAN, 16,
        Font.BOLD);
private static Font smallBold = new Font(Font.FontFamily.TIMES_ROMAN, 12,
        Font.BOLD);
private static Font small = new Font(Font.FontFamily.TIMES_ROMAN, 8,
        Font.ITALIC);

public static final String IMG1 = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/xyz/logo.png";





Context context;
String payMode;
String ChecqueNo;
String chequeDate;
String BankName;
String BalAmount,planName;
String Duration;
String StartDate,EndDate,PaidAmount;


String name,recieptNo, receiptDate, memberNo, mobileNo, payamount;



String[] DATA,RecieptData,MemberDATA,plandata;


public CreatePDF(Context context) {
    this.context = context;
}

public void createPDF(String ReceipData,String MemberData,String PayModdata,String PlanData,String bal)
{


    plandata = PlanData.split(",");
    planName=plandata[0];
    Duration=plandata[1];
    StartDate=plandata[2];
    EndDate=plandata[3];
    PaidAmount=plandata[4];


    MemberDATA = MemberData.split(",");
    name=MemberDATA[0];
    memberNo=MemberDATA[1];
    mobileNo=MemberDATA[2];
    payamount=MemberDATA[3];

    DATA = PayModdata.split(",");
    payMode=DATA[0];
    ChecqueNo=DATA[1];
    chequeDate=DATA[2];
    BankName=DATA[3];
    BalAmount=bal;

    RecieptData = ReceipData.split(",");
    recieptNo=RecieptData[0];
    receiptDate=RecieptData[1];



    Document doc = new Document();


    try {
        String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/xyz";

        File dir = new File(path);
        if(!dir.exists())
            dir.mkdirs();

        Log.d("PDFCreator", "PDF Path: " + path);


        DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd_ss");
        Date date = new Date();
        File file = new File(dir, name+"_"+recieptNo+".pdf");
        FileOutputStream fOut = new FileOutputStream(file);

        try {
            Document document = new Document();
            PdfWriter.getInstance(document, fOut);
            document.open();
            addMetaData(document);
            addTitlePage(document);
            document.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }



    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e("PDFCreator", "ioException:" + e);
    }  finally
    {
        doc.close();
    }

}


private static void addMetaData(Document document) {
    document.addTitle("Payment Report");
    document.addSubject("Using iText");
    document.addKeywords("Java, PDF, iText");
    document.addAuthor("author");
    document.addCreator("author");
}


private  void addTitlePage(Document document)
        throws IOException, DocumentException {
    Paragraph preface = new Paragraph();
    // We add one empty line
    addEmptyLine(preface, 1);
    // Lets write a big header






    Paragraph p=new Paragraph("Payment  Receipt", catFont);
    p.setAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER);
    preface.add(p);


    PdfPTable table55 = new PdfPTable(2);
    table55.setWidthPercentage(100);
    table55.setWidths(new int[]{1, 2});
    Image i=Image.getInstance(IMG1);
    i.scalePercent(50f);
    table55.addCell(createImageCell(i));
    table55.addCell(createTextCell("abc \n abc"));
    document.add(table55);
    Paragraph p1=new Paragraph(
            "Report generated At: , " + new Date(),
            smallBold);
    p1.setAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER);
    document.add(new LineSeparator());
    preface.add(p1);
    addEmptyLine(preface, 1);
    document.add(preface);
    document.add(new LineSeparator());
    document.add(Chunk.NEWLINE);
    PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(2);
    table.setWidthPercentage(100);
    table.addCell(getCell("Receipt No: "+recieptNo, PdfPCell.ALIGN_LEFT));
    table.addCell(getCell("Receipt Date: "+receiptDate, PdfPCell.ALIGN_CENTER));


    document.add(table);
    document.add(Chunk.NEWLINE);
    PdfPTable table1 = new PdfPTable(1);
    table1.setWidthPercentage(100);
    table1.addCell(getCell("Member No: "+memberNo, PdfPCell.ALIGN_LEFT));
    document.add(table1);
    document.add(Chunk.NEWLINE);


    PdfPTable table11 = new PdfPTable(1);
    table11.setWidthPercentage(100);
    table11.addCell(getCell("Mobile No: "+mobileNo, PdfPCell.ALIGN_LEFT));
    document.add(table11);
    document.add(Chunk.NEWLINE);
    PdfPTable table2 = new PdfPTable(5);
    table2.setWidthPercentage(100);
    table2.addCell(getBoldCell("Pay Mode: ", PdfPCell.ALIGN_LEFT));
    table2.addCell(getBoldCell("Cheque No: ", PdfPCell.ALIGN_CENTER));
    table2.addCell(getBoldCell("Cheque Date: ", PdfPCell.ALIGN_CENTER));
    table2.addCell(getBoldCell("Amount ", PdfPCell.ALIGN_CENTER));
    table2.addCell(getBoldCell("Bank Name:", PdfPCell.ALIGN_CENTER));
    document.add(table2);
    document.add(Chunk.NEWLINE);
    document.add(new LineSeparator());
    PdfPTable table2Copy = new PdfPTable(5);
    table2Copy.setWidthPercentage(100);
    table2Copy.addCell(getCell(payMode, PdfPCell.ALIGN_LEFT));
    table2Copy.addCell(getCell(ChecqueNo, PdfPCell.ALIGN_CENTER));
    table2Copy.addCell(getCell(chequeDate, PdfPCell.ALIGN_CENTER));
    table2Copy.addCell(getCell("Rs. :"+payamount+" INR", PdfPCell.ALIGN_CENTER));
    table2Copy.addCell(getCell(BankName, PdfPCell.ALIGN_CENTER));
    document.add(table2Copy);
    document.add(Chunk.NEWLINE);
    PdfPTable table3 = new PdfPTable(4);
    table3.setWidthPercentage(100);
    table3.addCell(getBoldCell("Plan Name: ", PdfPCell.ALIGN_LEFT));
    table3.addCell(getBoldCell("Duration: ", PdfPCell.ALIGN_CENTER));
    //table3.addCell(getBoldCell("Paid Amount ", PdfPCell.ALIGN_CENTER));
    table3.addCell(getBoldCell("Start Date:", PdfPCell.ALIGN_CENTER));
    table3.addCell(getBoldCell("End Date:", PdfPCell.ALIGN_CENTER));
    document.add(table3);
    document.add(Chunk.NEWLINE);
    document.add(new LineSeparator());
    PdfPTable table3Copy = new PdfPTable(4);
    table3Copy.setWidthPercentage(100);
    table3Copy.addCell(getCell(planName, PdfPCell.ALIGN_LEFT));
    table3Copy.addCell(getCell(Duration, PdfPCell.ALIGN_CENTER));
   // table3Copy.addCell(getCell(PaidAmount, PdfPCell.ALIGN_CENTER));
    table3Copy.addCell(getCell(StartDate, PdfPCell.ALIGN_CENTER));
    table3Copy.addCell(getCell(EndDate, PdfPCell.ALIGN_CENTER));

    document.add(table3Copy);
    document.add(Chunk.NEWLINE);







    Paragraph Para=new Paragraph(
            "Balance Amount : Rs. "+BalAmount+" INR", //$NON-NLS-1$ //$NON-NLS-2$ //$NON-NLS-3$
            smallBold);
    Para.setAlignment(Element.ALIGN_LEFT);
    document.add(Para);
    document.add(Chunk.NEWLINE);
    document.add(new LineSeparator());


    Paragraph ParaTsys=new Paragraph(
            "name", //$NON-NLS-1$ //$NON-NLS-2$ //$NON-NLS-3$
            small);
    ParaTsys.setAlignment(Element.ALIGN_RIGHT);
    document.add(ParaTsys);

}

public PdfPCell getCell(String text, int alignment) {
    PdfPCell cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(text));
    cell.setPadding(0);
    cell.setHorizontalAlignment(alignment);
    cell.setBorder(PdfPCell.NO_BORDER);
    return cell;
}

public PdfPCell getBoldCell(String text, int alignment) {
    Phrase f= new Phrase(text);
    f.setFont(subFont);
    PdfPCell cell = new PdfPCell(f);
    cell.setPadding(0);
    cell.setHorizontalAlignment(alignment);
    cell.setBorder(PdfPCell.NO_BORDER);
    return cell;
}
public static PdfPCell createImageCell(String path,int align) throws DocumentException, IOException {
    Image img = Image.getInstance(path);
    img.scaleAbsolute(100f, 100f);
    img.setAbsolutePosition(500f, 650f);
    PdfPCell cell = new PdfPCell(img, true);
    cell.setHorizontalAlignment(align);
    return cell;
}
private static void addEmptyLine(Paragraph paragraph, int number) {
    for (int i = 0; i < number; i++) {
        paragraph.add(new Paragraph(" "));
    }
}








public static PdfPCell createImageCell(Image img) throws DocumentException, IOException {
    PdfPCell cell = new PdfPCell(img, true);
    cell.setBorder(PdfPCell.NO_BORDER);
    return cell;
}


public static PdfPCell createTextCell(String text) throws DocumentException, IOException {
    PdfPCell cell = new PdfPCell();
    Paragraph p = new Paragraph(text);
    p.setAlignment(Element.ALIGN_RIGHT);
    cell.addElement(p);
    cell.setVerticalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_BOTTOM);
    cell.setBorder(PdfPCell.NO_BORDER);
    return cell;
} }
And Call method like this

 CreatePDF createPDFf= new CreatePDF(PaymentActivity.this);   
createPDFf.createPDF(ReceiptData,MemberData,PayModeData,PlanData,String.valueOf(Bal));
```

Same way kindly provide solution for Internal Storage using InBuilt Feature FILEPROVIDER of Android.

Above code is storing in External Storage. Nowadays almost each phone has enough space in Internal Memory so no need of External. In Such case, i wish to store and retrieve pdf after creating and generating the same.

kindly suggest changes.

Comment: Please check below link for this issue. https://stackoverflow.com/a/55456407/651377

Answer (score 1):

> Same way kindly provide solution for Internal Storage using InBuilt Feature FILEPROVIDER of Android

Instead of:

```
   String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/xyz";

    File dir = new File(path);
```

You would use:

```
File dir = new File(context.getFilesDir(), "xyz");
```

`FileProvider` is not needed for writing to internal storage.

> Nowadays almost each phone has enough space in Internal Memory so no need of External

The decision of whether to use [internal storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2017/11/13/storage-situation-internal-storage.html) or [external storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2017/11/14/storage-situation-external-storage.html) is not made based on space. Both internal storage and external storage are on the same partition on most Android devices, and so they consume the same space.

Instead, the question is: does the user need independent access to this PDF file, through file managers and similar tools?

If the answer is "yes", use external storage. If the answer is "no", use internal storage.

---

In addition:

- Please do disk I/O on a background thread
- Please do not clutter up the root of external storage with files

Comment: Thankyou Sir for your suggesstions. I am currently updating code as per answer given. Let you know whether it works or not. FILEPROVIDER i wish to view that created PDF which will be stored in Internal Storage as per your answer. FILEPROVIDER will also help me to share that pdf thus can you suggest steps for FILEPROVIDER or viewing that pdf.

Comment: @Umang: [The `FileProvider` documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/FileProvider) has instructions for using it. Given the code snippet in my answer, the `FileProvider` configuration element would be `<files-path name="whatever" path="xyz" />` (where you can use whatever simple string that you like for `whatever`).

Comment: Code is updated and there is no error but where can i see this file inside xyz directory? please let me know

Comment: @Umang: In Android Studio, open the Device File Explorer view. By default, this is docked in the lower right corner. In there, try visiting `/data/data/.../files/`, where `...` is your `applicationId`.

Comment: Sir I am running in my Android Smart Phone.

Comment: @Umang: Android Studio's Device File Explorer allows you to view the files of debuggable apps on Android devices, as well as on emulators. If you mean that you are not using Android Studio, but instead are developing the app directly on the phone (e.g., using AIDE), then you have no access to this directory, except through your own app's code.