# Unable to open PDF from internal storage for viewing on Android 8 and 9 using File Provider

Tags: android, pdf, android-9.0-pie, android-8.1-oreo

For Android 8 and 9 only.

I have a PDF filer here -

```
String url = "file:///storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.verna.poc/files/Download/mypdf.pdf";
```

I'm trying to open this file for viewing using this -

```
File file= new File(url);
file.setReadable(true, false);

Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
Uri pdfUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(getApplicationContext(), BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID + ".provider", file);
intent.setDataAndType(pdfUri, "application/pdf");
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION);

List<ResolveInfo> resInfoList = getApplicationContext().getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities(intent, PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY);
    for (ResolveInfo resolveInfo : resInfoList) {
        String packageName = resolveInfo.activityInfo.packageName;
        getApplicationContext().grantUriPermission(packageName, pdfUri,
                Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION | Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
    }

Intent in = Intent.createChooser(intent, "Open File");
startActivity(in);
```

The File chooser option is opening and when I open the file using Google PDF reader, the PDF reader opens and closes immediately. Whats wrong in my code ?

Comment: have you provided read write permission?

Comment: yes i have. my manifest has these - <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

Comment: they need runtime confirmation from user, did you do that?

Comment: yes. i have given runtime persmissions for these as well. still not working.

Answer (score 1):

access the file from within the app which owns that private directory - an `Intent` won't cut it, because this could have been sent by just any application. and if it has to be a file-chooser `Intent`, then create a shared directory for your app on the SD card, where any application can access it; the regular `Downloads` directory would also be suitable for that.
another option (as initially suggested) would be to create a simple file-chooser, which resides within the application, so that no `Intent` would be required to select a file... this all has certain advances and dis-advances; choose the one possibility, which suits you the best... in general, it's private vs. shared storage location.

Comment: but im using file provider for sharing an internal file to be accessed by a third party app. File providers are used for that purpose, i guess. it would be great if you can give a working solution.

Comment: @Gissipi_453 you are creating an `Intent`, which is supposed to be fulfilled by another application, while such one is being installed ... see the documentation: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#createChooser(android.content.Intent,%20java.lang.CharSequence) ... that's why messing around with uri-permissions is required - which otherwise would not be required. you could also set it in `Manifest.xml` already: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/grant-uri-permission-element ...matching all PDF in there.

Comment: ... while you already grant access, better just use external storage - because then it will be an SD card, (while one is present). with a few files your approach is just fine, with a few hundred or thousands of files, this can get problematic. it doesn't scale nicely - because clearing the data (just try with settings > applications) will delete them altogether, which is not the case with external storage.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to share a file from internal storage with the another  app. You will need to create a file provider for this to work. You will need to specify a directory which you want the file provider to generate Uris for

> FileProvider is a special subclass of ContentProvider that facilitates secure sharing of files associated with an app by creating a content:// Uri for a file instead of a file:/// Uri.
>
> A FileProvider can only generate a content URI for files in directories that you specify beforehand. To specify a directory, specify the its storage area and path in XML, using child elements of the  element. For example, the following paths element tells FileProvider that you intend to request content URIs for the images/ subdirectory of your private file area.

This answer has a good example on this

[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52789578/how-to-open-pdf-file-from-internal-storage-in-oreo)

Here is the doc page for `FileProvider`

[FileProvider](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/FileProvider)

Comment: thanks for the answer. im already using a file provider as you can see in my question. as i figured out later, the issue was with how i was using my file path. When you are making a new file using, File file = new File(path), don't add file:// infront of the path.

Comment: @Gissipi_453 it would expect protocol scheme `content://`, which can be omitted (most likely because there only is 1 protocol scheme to "choose" from - and so it is known which one to use, unless telling it otherwise).

Answer (score 1):

In this we first save the file to internal storage and then read from it using external app.

I use below method to save the file in internal storage :

```
private void savePDFtoInternalStorage(byte[] pdfAsBytes){
    //Save in internal memo cache
    File directory = mFragmentActivity.getFilesDir();
    //updating path for pdf to match with file_path.xml
    mCardStmtFile = new File(directory.getAbsolutePath(), "sample.pdf");
    OutputStream outputStream = null;
    try {
        PbLogger.e(TAG, "writing to mStmtFile");
        outputStream = new FileOutputStream(mCardStmtFile, false);
        outputStream.write(pdfAsBytes);
        outputStream.flush();
        outputStream.close();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();

    }
}
```

PFB the file provider declared file_path.xml:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <paths>
      <files-path path="/" name="secretpdf" />
   </paths>
```

PFB the Android Manifest Entry for file provider :

```
    <provider
        android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
        android:authorities="com.***.********.provider"
        android:exported="false"
        android:grantUriPermissions="true">
        <!-- ressource file to create -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
            android:resource="@xml/file_paths">
        </meta-data>
    </provider>
```

Use below code to launch PDF :

```
 Intent intentShareFile = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        if (mStmtFile.exists()) {
            intentShareFile.setType("application/pdf");
            Uri fileUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(
                    mFragmentActivity,
                    "com.****.********.provider",
                    mCardStmtFile);
            intentShareFile.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, fileUri);
            intentShareFile.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT,
                    getDescription());
            //adding grant read permission to share internal file
            intentShareFile.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intentShareFile, "Share File"));
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the issue. When you are making a new file using, File file = new File(path), don't add `file://` infront of the path.

This is correct -

```
String url = "/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.verna.poc/files/Download/mypdf.pdf";
File file= new File(url);
```

This is wrong -

```
String url = "file:///storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.verna.poc/files/Download/mypdf.pdf";
File file= new File(url);
```